# How to populate a dropdown by values of another dropdown in mvc sql server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, model-view-controller

I have a dropdown populated with state. and another dropdown(city) should populate based on the selection of state. Any ideas?

This is my model for city dropdown list:

```
public List <SelectListItem> Add()
{
    List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
    connection();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("proccountry_dropdown1", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pstroperationflag", "S-city");
    con.Open();
    using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (sdr.Read())
        {
            items.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = sdr["city"].ToString(),
                Value = sdr["city"].ToString()
            });
        }
    }
    con.Close();
    return items;
}
```

This is my SQL server code:

```
ELSE IF @pstrOperationFlag = 'S-city'
    BEGIN
        SET @strSqlQry  = 'SELECT city FROM '
        SET @strSqlQry  = @strSqlQry + 'country_dropdown1'
        PRINT @strSqlQry
        EXECUTE(@strSqlQry)
    END
```

Comment: By default you can keep the city dropdown empty.Write a onchange event for state dropdown and populate the data for the city dropdown on selection of state dropdown.

Comment: what is the code for that mate??

Comment: It seems to me, that you don't understand MVC properly. Also, there is code and explanation missing in your question. If you get those, I am pretty sure you will find suitable code online.

Comment: take a look at this http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-simple-cascading-dropdownlist-in-mvc/ (How to create cascading DropDownlist)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make ajax call for fetching city details on-change event of state :

**Your View Page :**

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
     // get region list
        $('#StateId').change(function () {
            $.getJSON('/Home/GetCityList/' + $('#StateId').val(), function (data) {
                var items = '<option>-Select City-</option>';
                $.each(data, function (i, region) {
                    items += "<option value='" + region.Value + "'>" + region.Text + "</option>";
                });
                $('#CityId').html(items);
            });
        });
 });
</script>
```

**And Your Controller Action :**

```
  public JsonResult GetCityList(int? Id)
  {
    var citylist = _userService.GetAllCity().Where(p => p.StateId == Id).ToList();
     IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList = from s in citylist
                                                         select new SelectListItem
                                                         {
                                                             Value = Convert.ToString(s.Id),
                                                             Text = s.Name
                                                         };
     return Json(new SelectList(selectList, "Value", "Text"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
```

**And your drop-down on view :**

```html
 <td>@Html.DropDownList("StateId", new SelectList(Model.StateList, "Id", "Name"), "-Select State-", new { @class = "form-control" }) </td>
<td>@Html.DropDownList("CityId", new SelectList(Model.CityList, "Id", "Name"), "-Select City-", new { @class = "form-control" })</td>
```

Comment: where should I make ajax call bro??

Comment: On your view page

Comment: inside script tag bro??

Comment: var Strength = _masterService.GetAllstrength().Where(p => p.Medication == Id).ToList();
Error CS0103 The name '_masterService' does not exist in the current context

Comment: This CityList "var citylist = _userService.GetAllCity().Where(p => p.StateId == Id).ToList();" you need to call from your database

Comment: you have that already public List <SelectListItem> Add()
 method just fetch all data and stored in  var citylist object

Answer (score 0):

You can just place "$('#StateId').change(function () ... " code in $(document).ready(function(){....});   and it will work.